# Upgraded domain controller from Win 2k to Win 2k8r2 and need to move Terminal Server into new domain

Tags: domain, windows-terminal-services

For a number of reasons, I have created a new, separate domain in my organization in Windows Server 2008 R2. I have a Terminal Server machine that also hosts the TS License Server that I need to remove from the old domain (Win 2k) and add to the new domain ((Win 2k8 r2).

Aside from changing access for the Terminal Server users to the newly created domain accounts, what other changes will I need to make to avoid any remote access problems, and what other problems can I expect when I do this?

Any insight is appreciated.